# How to make a gradent constant-glow with gradient shadow button in android?

Tags: android, android-button, glow

I know this topic has been discussed before but I didn't find really what I am looking for.

I have those buttons (screenshot at the bottom). Now I want to add a constant outer glow. Is there another possibility to do this than saving it as .png in the drawable folder? That would make much less work.
Thank you!

[image]

Comment: these are shadows

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I make an animated/constant glowing effect around button in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45704019/how-can-i-make-an-animated-constant-glowing-effect-around-button-in-android)

Comment: No, there are just solid color shadow I want to gradient color shadow

Comment: @Zhu Take a look at my answer. There you have different gradients for your shadow. Hope it can still help you :)

Comment: I found better solution here https://habr.com/ru/post/530376/

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for that `Button` in your image. I combined a library with my own `drawable` and used a trick with a `stroke` to reach the `Button` you were searching for. Take a look at my [main answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68583069/how-to-put-shadow-with-gradient). I made the exact sample you wanted as a little Spoiler:

[image: Result]