# How can i make a glow button in android

Tags: java, android

How can i make a glow button
To make its edges look luminous

[image: glow buttons]

As in the picture

**in java code**

Any help please

Comment: Do you have an answer here? https://stackoverflow.com/a/45711115/13685592

Comment: Yes i did,but i don't need to apply animation ! I just want there to be lighting around the button, any help bro

Answer (score 0):

I found the tutorial for this particular implementation [here](https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/7866)! I believe it will solve your issue.

Comment: Thank you sir ,,   but i wanna do it without use any library , help me if you can please